# Unrealscript splitting a string

Tags: udk

Note, this is repost from stackoverflow - I have only just discovered this site :)

I need to split a string in Unrealscript, in the same way that Java's split function works.

For instance - return the string "foo" as an array of char.

I have tried to use the SplitString function:

> array SplitString( string Source, optional string Delimiter=",", optional bool bCullEmpty ) Wrapper for splitting a string into an array of strings using a single expression.

as found at http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UnrealScriptFunctions.html but it returns the entire String.

```
simulated function wordDraw() {

local String inputString;
inputString = "trolls";
local string whatwillitbe;
local int b;
local int x;
local array<String> letterArray;

letterArray = SplitString(inputString,, false);
for (x = 0; x < letterArray.Length; x++)
{
        whatwillitbe = letterArray[x];
        `log('it will be '@whatwillitbe);
        b = letterarray.Length;
        `log('letterarray length is '@b);
        `log('letter number '@x);
}
```

}

Output is:

b returns:

> 1

whatwillitbe returns:

> `trolls`

However I would like b to return 6 and whatwillitbe to return each character individually.

I have had a few answers proposed, however, I would still like to properly understand how the **SplitString** function works. For instance, if the Delimiter parameter is optional, what does the function use as a delimiter by default?

Comment: Please don't cross-post between sites, especially since your [question there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261878/unrealscript-splitting-a-string) already has answers.

Answer (score 1):

The default delimiter is ',' see http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/StringsInUnrealScript.html

For your problem you could use Mid() to generate your array by hand.

> ```
> string Mid ( coerce string S, int i, optional int j )
> ```
>
> The Mid() function generates a substring of S by starting at character
>   i and copying j characters. If j is omitted, the rest of the string is
>   copied. i is clamped between 0 and the length of the string. j is
>   clamped between i and the length of the string. If S is not a string,
>   its value will attempt to be converted to a string value.

You want to loop from 0 to the string length and generate substrings of length = 1 .
Pseudocode:

```
for (i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
{
  letterArray[i]=Mid(inputString,i,1);
}
```